# odoo 10 Addon view not being used

Tags: python, odoo-10, odoo

I've created a new module in order to extend `sale.advance.payment.inv`. The problem is that the form from my module is not being used, it is being used the default form (and also the new values defined in my module are not being loaded in the old form...)

I'm using this files:

**__manifest__.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "invoice_sales_order",
    'summary': """Allows invoice percentage for each line in sales order""",
    'description': """
        Allows invoice percentage for each line in sales order
    """,
    'author': "Miquel",
    'website': "http://example.com",
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.5',
    'depends': ['base', 'account', 'Sales'],
    'data': [
        'views/views.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
}
```

**controllers/controllers.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.

import time

from odoo import api, fields, models, _
from odoo.addons import decimal_precision as dp
from odoo.exceptions import UserError


class SaleAdvancePaymentInv(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "sale.advance.payment.inv"

    @api.model
    def _count(self):
        return len(self._context.get('active_ids', []))

    @api.model
    def _get_advance_payment_method(self):
        if self._count() == 1:
            sale_obj = self.env['sale.order']
            order = sale_obj.browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))[0]
            if all([line.product_id.invoice_policy == 'order' for line in order.order_line]) or order.invoice_count:
                return 'all'
        return 'delivered'

    advance_payment_method = fields.Selection([
        ('delivered', 'Invoiceable lines'),
        ('all', 'Invoiceable lines (deduct down payments and quantity percentage)'),
        ('soprecentage', 'Quantity percentage line by line'),
        ('percentage', 'Down payment (percentage)'),
        ('fixed', 'Down payment (fixed amount)')
        ], string='What do you want to invoice?', default=_get_advance_payment_method, required=True)

    @api.onchange('advance_payment_method')
    def onchange_advance_payment_method(self):
        if self.advance_payment_method == 'percentage' or self.advance_payment_method == 'soprecentage':
            return {'value': {'amount': 0}}
        return {}

    @api.multi
    def _create_invoice(self, order, so_line, amount):
        inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
        ir_property_obj = self.env['ir.property']

        account_id = False
        if self.product_id.id:
            account_id = self.product_id.property_account_income_id.id
        if not account_id:
            inc_acc = ir_property_obj.get('property_account_income_categ_id', 'product.category')
            account_id = order.fiscal_position_id.map_account(inc_acc).id if inc_acc else False
        if not account_id:
            raise UserError(
                _('There is no income account defined for this product: "%s". You may have to install a chart of account from Accounting app, settings menu.') %
                (self.product_id.name,))

        if self.amount <= 0.00:
            raise UserError(_('The value of the down payment amount must be positive.'))
        context = {'lang': order.partner_id.lang}
        if self.advance_payment_method == 'percentage' or self.advance_payment_method == 'soprecentage':
            amount = order.amount_untaxed * self.amount / 100
            name = _("Down payment of %s%%") % (self.amount,)
        else:
            amount = self.amount
            name = _('Down Payment')
        del context
        taxes = self.product_id.taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: not order.company_id or r.company_id == order.company_id)
        if order.fiscal_position_id and taxes:
            tax_ids = order.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes).ids
        else:
            tax_ids = taxes.ids

        invoice_line_ids = []
        sale_line_obj = self.env['sale.order.line']
        for line in sale_line_obj:
            if not line.is_downpayment:
                invoice_line_ids.append((0, 0, {
                    'name': line.name,
                    'origin': order.name,
                    'account_id': account_id,
                    'price_unit': line.price_unit,
                    'quantity': line.product_uom_qty * self.amount / 100,
                    'discount': line.discount,
                    'uom_id': line.product_uom,
                    'product_id': line.product_id,
                    'sale_line_ids': [(6, 0, [line.id])],
                    'invoice_line_tax_ids': line.tax_id,
                    'account_analytic_id': order.analytic_account_id.id or False,
                }))

        invoice = inv_obj.create({
            'name': order.client_order_ref or order.name,
            'origin': order.name,
            'type': 'out_invoice',
            'reference': False,
            'account_id': order.partner_id.property_account_receivable_id.id,
            'partner_id': order.partner_invoice_id.id,
            'partner_shipping_id': order.partner_shipping_id.id,
            'invoice_line_ids': invoice_line_ids,
            'currency_id': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
            'payment_term_id': order.payment_term_id.id,
            'fiscal_position_id': order.fiscal_position_id.id or order.partner_id.property_account_position_id.id,
            'team_id': order.team_id.id,
            'user_id': order.user_id.id,
            'comment': order.note,
        })
        invoice.compute_taxes()
        invoice.message_post_with_view('mail.message_origin_link',
                    values={'self': invoice, 'origin': order},
                    subtype_id=self.env.ref('mail.mt_note').id)
        return invoice

    @api.multi
    def create_invoices(self):
        sale_orders = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', []))

        if self.advance_payment_method == 'delivered':
            sale_orders.action_invoice_create()
        elif self.advance_payment_method == 'all':
            sale_orders.action_invoice_create(final=True)
        else:
            # Create deposit product if necessary
            if not self.product_id:
                vals = self._prepare_deposit_product()
                self.product_id = self.env['product.product'].create(vals)
                self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('sale.default_deposit_product_id', self.product_id.id)

            sale_line_obj = self.env['sale.order.line']
            for order in sale_orders:
                if self.advance_payment_method == 'percentage' or self.advance_payment_method == 'soprecentage':
                    amount = order.amount_untaxed * self.amount / 100
                else:
                    amount = self.amount
                if self.product_id.invoice_policy != 'order':
                    raise UserError(_('The product used to invoice a down payment should have an invoice policy set to "Ordered quantities". Please update your deposit product to be able to create a deposit invoice.'))
                if self.product_id.type != 'service':
                    raise UserError(_("The product used to invoice a down payment should be of type 'Service'. Please use another product or update this product."))
                taxes = self.product_id.taxes_id.filtered(lambda r: not order.company_id or r.company_id == order.company_id)
                if order.fiscal_position_id and taxes:
                    tax_ids = order.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes).ids
                else:
                    tax_ids = taxes.ids
                context = {'lang': order.partner_id.lang}
                so_line = sale_line_obj.create({
                    'name': _('Advance: %s') % (time.strftime('%m %Y'),),
                    'price_unit': amount,
                    'product_uom_qty': 0.0,
                    'order_id': order.id,
                    'discount': 0.0,
                    'product_uom': self.product_id.uom_id.id,
                    'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                    'tax_id': [(6, 0, tax_ids)],
                    'is_downpayment': True,
                })
                del context
                self._create_invoice(order, so_line, amount)
        if self._context.get('open_invoices', False):
            return sale_orders.action_view_invoice()
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

**views/views.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <record id="view_sale_advance_payment_inv" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Invoice Orders</field>
            <field name="model">sale.advance.payment.inv</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Invoice Sales Order">
                    <p class="oe_grey">
                        Invoices will be created in draft so that you can review
                        them before validation.
                    </p>
                    <p class="oe_grey">
                        Invoices will be created in draft so that you can review
                        them before validation.
                    </p>
                    <group>
                        <field name="count" invisible="[('count','=',1)]" readonly="True"/>
                        <field name="advance_payment_method" class="oe_inline" widget="radio"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('count','&gt;',1)]}"/>
                        <field name="product_id"
                            context="{'search_default_services': 1, 'default_type': 'service', 'default_invoice_policy': 'order'}" class="oe_inline"
                            attrs="{'invisible': 1}"/>
                        <label for="amount" attrs="{'invisible': [('advance_payment_method', 'not in', ('fixed','percentage'))]}"/>
                        <div attrs="{'invisible': [('advance_payment_method', 'not in', ('fixed','percentage'))]}">
                            <field name="amount"
                                attrs="{'required': [('advance_payment_method', 'in', ('fixed','percentage'))]}" class="oe_inline" widget="monetary"/>
                            <label string="%%"
                                attrs="{'invisible': [('advance_payment_method', '!=', 'percentage')]}" class="oe_inline"/>
                        </div>
                        <field name="deposit_account_id" class="oe_inline"
                            attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('advance_payment_method', 'not in', ('fixed', 'percentage')), ('product_id', '!=', False)]}" groups="account.group_account_manager"/>
                        <field name="deposit_taxes_id" class="oe_inline" widget="many2many_tags"
                            domain="[('type_tax_use','=','sale')]"
                            attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('advance_payment_method', 'not in', ('fixed', 'percentage')), ('product_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="create_invoices" string="Create and View Invoices" type="object"
                            context="{'open_invoices': True}" class="btn-primary"/>
                        <button name="create_invoices" string="Create Invoices" type="object"
                            class="btn-primary"/>
                        <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Invoice Order</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">sale.advance.payment.inv</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
        </record>

        <!-- TODO: check if we need this -->
        <record model="ir.values" id="sale_order_line_make_invoice">
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line" />
            <field name="name">Invoice Orders</field>
            <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
            <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv'))" />
            <field name="key">action</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        </record>

</odoo>
```

I'm really desperated, many many hours trying different things and don't see the light...

Answer (score 1):

I've found it, manifest was wrong:

**__manifest__.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "invoice_sales_order",
    'summary': """Allows invoice percentage for each line in sales order""",
    'description': """
        Allows invoice percentage for each line in sales order
    """,
    'author': "Miquel",
    'website': "http://example.com",
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.5',
    'depends': ['base', 'account', 'sale'],
    'data': [
        'views/views.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
}
```